Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights + AddStandardResilienceHandler = ComponentNotRegisteredException
My project uses Serilog and syncs logs to App Insights via Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights with a call to services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(); and configuration like this:
.UseSerilog((context, services, loggerConfiguration) =>
{
  loggerConfiguration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
      services.GetRequiredService<TelemetryConfiguration>(),
      TelemetryConverter.Traces);
    //.WriteTo.Async(c => c.OpenTelemetry());
});

That works fine.  However, when I try to add .NET Aspire the above configuration code fails to retrieve TelemetryConfiguration with the following error:
Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: 'The requested service 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration' has not been registered
After digging some more the error is caused by the SerivceDefaults projects and in particular:
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpClientDefaults(http =>
{
  http.AddStandardResilienceHandler();
}

If I comment out AddStandardResilienceHandler() DI is suddenly able to find TelemetryConfiguration again.  Why?  How can I get both?
UPDATE
I found a workaround.  It works if I do this
.WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
    MakeTelemetryConfiguration(builder),
    TelemetryConverter.Traces);

private static TelemetryConfiguration MakeTelemetryConfiguration(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var disableAppInsightsTelemetry = string.IsNullOrEmpty(builder.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"]);
    if (disableAppInsightsTelemetry)
    {
        return new TelemetryConfiguration
        {
            DisableTelemetry = true,
        };
    }

    return new TelemetryConfiguration
    {
        InstrumentationKey = builder.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"],
    };
}

but that doesn't feel right, and I'd rather keep my original configuration if possible.

Could you please include the exception stacktrace as well?
